# "will have had" insted of "will have" - grammar

Tags: grammar

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/russian-pullback-caused-by-conscription-problems-2014-5

> Felgenhauer notes that it would be possible to keep conscripts for only a few months longer than their contracts called for — but that would run the risk of a drastic slip in morale as soldiers overstayed their expected conscription period.
>   Meanwhile, the arriving batch of Russian conscripts **will have had** limited training, reducing their battle effectiveness.
>   The incoming round of conscripts will serve within Russian airborne units, marines, and army brigades.

I don't understand why it should be **will have had** instead of simple **will have**. Could you please explain this grammar point to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form *will have had* is the [future perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_perfect#English), which allows you to describe an event that will be complete at some time in the future. This distinct from *will have*, which is the [simple future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_future#Simple_future) and describes an event that will occur in the future.

1. The arriving batch of Russian conscripts *will have had* limited training.
   The arriving conscripts will have *already* completed training, which was limited.
2. The arriving batch of Russian conscripts *will have* limited training.
   The arriving conscripts will either:

   - have *already* completed training, which was limited, or;
   - be given training, which will be limited.

The context definitely requires that the first meaning, not the second, be conveyed.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Whoops, realised my glosses weren't entirely clear. But I was demonstrating the difference between the two, rather than providing both as possibilities.

Comment: No worries, I realized I didn't read your post as carefully as I should have to begin with. Sorry about that.